# Redirecting to URL within a POST Request

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, post

I've been searching around but couldn't seem to find an answer to this...

I'm really new to NodeJS. I'm trying to write a server that will take the POST request when user try to login, then redirect to the home page using GET, and the home page will now display the username.

so if the url is `home.html`, on the page it says `guest`, if the url is `home.html?username=adam` then on the page it says `adam`

On my `login.html`, there's a form similar to this

```
<FORM ACTION="login.html" METHOD="POST">
  <CENTER>
  Username: <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="username" required=true><BR>
  Password: <INPUT TYPE="password" ID="password" required=true><BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
  </CENTER>
</FORM>
```

On my `server.js`, I have the block trying to get the username and redirect

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if(req.url == "login.html" && req.method == "POST")
  {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      var someData += chunk;
      var username = //get from POST data

      //attempt to redirect
      res.writeHead(200, {"Location":"home,html?username=adam"});
      res.end();
    });
  }
}
```

I was able to get the username and log it, but when I tried to redirect, the page came back blank, and the url still says login.html...

I'm not even sure if I'm doing it correctly, please help.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to nodejs please try to use REST API for communication instead of redirecting to other pages directly.

To retrieve the form data in server js you need to install body parser which is detailed here:

[https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser][1]

Then update your server js like below:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('login.html');
});
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('home.html');
});
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

    console.log("Username:",req.body.username);
    console.log("password:",req.body.password);//just for reference do not show anywhere
    res.redirect('/home?username='+req.body.username);
});



http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And your login login.html will looks like this:

```
<FORM ACTION="/login" METHOD="POST">
  <CENTER>
  Username: <INPUT TYPE="text" name="username" ID="username" required=true><BR>
  Password: <INPUT TYPE="password" name="password" ID="password" required=true><BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
  </CENTER>
</FORM>
```

Do necessary action on home page as now you are avail with username on url..hope this help..let me know if any doubts. Happy coding:)